# What is the simplest way to create nested objects in Ebean?

Tags: java, playframework, orm, nested, ebean

I need two Ebean model classes called "States" and "Children". A "State" object can contain nested Child objects(List of children).

Here is the basic States class,

```
@Entity
public class States extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Constraints.Required(message = "stateName cannot be null")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String statename;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String url;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String parent;

    private List<Children> childrenList;
}
```

Here is the basic Children class,

```
@Entity
public class Children extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String statename;

    @Column
    private String child;
}
```

What are the minimal modifications that should be done to these classes to create State objects using Ebean ORM? I went through the post,

> [Ebean Query by OneToMany Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202490/ebean-query-by-onetomany-relationship)

But there, a lot of changes have been suggested. I just want the minimal modifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do was, doing a small modification to the "States" class,

```
@Entity
public class States extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Constraints.Required(message = "stateName cannot be null")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String statename;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String url;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String parent;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Children> childrenList;
}
```

Only change I have done here is,

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

I did not do any changes to the "Children" class. Before starting the play app I set

`play.evolutions.enabled = true`

in "application.conf" file. Then using the evolution SQL file that was created in "evolution.default" folder, I adjusted the schema of the database. After that "States" objects were created successfully with nested "Children" objects.

Comment: Technically with Ebean you do not need ... @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) ... and I would personally leave this off and let Ebean choose the appropriate identity mechanism to use for the given DB platform.